# How can I import lxc containers back from the snapshots the lxc create just before the `lxc snap` is removed?

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I have the following situation:

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 node, which used to have [lxd v5](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd) installed through snap. It used to have 3 containers, at the moment of remove the lxd using the `snap remove lxd` [it did take a snapshot of all the containers](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/sudo-snap-remove-lxd-seems-to-take-a-very-long-time/8712/2?u=kcyborg), but when I try to import those snapshoted containers I got some errors.

First, the snapshots were deliver to me in .zip format, which when I try to import using the `lxc import file_name.zip` I get the *Importing instance: 100% (108.71MB/s)Error: Unsupported compression* error, weird because as I pointed I got the snapshots in .zip format.

So I needed to extract it and then compress it again using tar (`tar -czvf containers.tar.gz file_contains_extracteds/`)

Once I got the correct format, then I try to import it, but I get the following error:

```
lxc import containers.tar.gz
Importing instance: 100% (701.66MB/s)Error: Backup is missing at "backup/index.yaml"
```

When I look into the extracted .zip file I get:

```
ls
25112  archive.tgz  common  meta.json  meta.sha3_384  user
```

And inside the `common` there are all the container's folder:

```
ls common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/
monitor  orch1  vrouter
```

So, the question is: How can I import lxc containers back from the snapshots the lxc create just before the lxc snap is removed?